# autoref figure labels in tufte-book

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, listings, tufte, autoref

This seems to be an issue with tufte-book figure labeling but I'm not sure whether it's something I can work around.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{listings}\lstloadlanguages{C}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\lstnumberautorefname}{Figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        a & b \\
        c & d
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \caption{A table}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    void main() {}
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{A listing}\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        a & b \\
        c & d
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Another table}\label{fig3}
\end{figure}

testing \autoref{fig} and \autoref{fig2} and \autoref{fig3}
\end{document}
```

The two `\autoref` targeting the tables seem to be incorrect: the last line prints as "testing [1] and [Figure 2] and [Figure 3]" where the [1] links to the start of the document, [Figure 2] links to figure 2 as expected, and [Figure 3] also links to figure 2. The same behavior occurs if the figure contains text or other things instead of a table. So it seems like the `lstlisting` environment is doing some hackery to fix the references and the default behavior is failing to anchor the label correctly.

Can I add some magic sauce to the other figures to make them work like the listings figure?

Comment: try with `\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book}`. then the class will not load hyperref and hyperref can overwrite the \@caption definition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that worked. Could you convert it to an answer? (Do you know the reason for the conflict?)